# MySql Type Data for users points

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

i've try using varchar, the problems below :
if the points 1000, then minus 10000, it'll not change the value to -9000.

then try again using int, the problems :
points can't have any , (comma) like  10000.21 it'll change the value to 10000

any ideas of this?

Comment: how about using `DOUBLE` ?

Comment: @insanebits no DOUBLE can't has minus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DECIMAL datatype if you want to use decimals :)

EDIT:

Standard SQL requires that DECIMAL(6,2) be able to store any value with five digits and two decimals, so values that can be stored in the salary column range from -9999.99 to 9999.99

Comment: decimal allowing minus ? like -9000 ?

Comment: Yes, DECIMAL(6,2) will allow upto -9999.99 and 9999.99. Tweak the numbers to allow for bigger or smaller ranges

Answer (score 1):

Just use DECIMAL data type.
INT can't be decimal.
EDIT: Yeah, DECIMAL, not DOUBLE.

Comment: decimal allowing minus ?  like -9000 ?

Comment: Yes, it's not an unsigned number.